# proof by induction that $a_n$ < 5, when $ a_{n+1} = \frac{6a_n + 5}{a_n + 2} $

Tags: induction

$ a_1 = 1, $

$ a_{n+1}  = \frac{6a_n + 5}{a_n + 2} $ (where n is a +ve integer)

we have to prove by induction that $ a_n $ is always less than 5.

so I used induction to prove that $ a_n $ is always positive.

And i calculated $ a_2 = \frac{11}{3} $ for the base case

then we assume that $ a_k < 5 $

so $ 6a_k + 5 < 35 $  and $ a_k + 2 > 2 $

so $ a_{n+1}  = \frac{6a_n + 5}{a_n + 2} < \frac{35}{2} = 17.5 $ --> equation 1

so I figured if i could get a bigger value for the denominator, this approach would work. so i tried calculating the biggest value $ a_k $ can take (i drew a graph) , but it turns out that it is 5 (what i mean is that while $ a_n < 5, a_{n+1} >  a_n $, but when $ a_n > 5 $  then the value of $ a_{n+1} < a_n $

However, this doesn't prove $a_n < 5 $, it proves that $ a_n <= 5 $

so I just substitute this in equation 1, instead of 35/2 write 35/7 and get the result

finally, my question is, is there an easier way to do this? a major part of my result relies on the graph,, so is there any way i could do it using induction only?

Comment: Well the closed-form for $a_n$ is $a_n = 5 - \frac{84}{7^n+14}$, so from this we see immediately that $a_n<5$. But I'm assuming it would be more difficult to find this closed form by hand than it would be to prove $a_n<5$ by induction.

Comment: $a_{n+1}=\frac {6a_n +5}{a_n+2} = \frac{6a_n + 12 -7}{a_n + 2} =\frac {6a_n + 12}{a_n + n} - \frac 7{a_n +2} =6-\frac 7{a_n+2}$.  If $a_n < 5$ then $\frac7{a_n+2}  > \frac 77$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $0<a_n<5$.

Then $a_{n+1}=6-\frac{7}{a_n+2}<6-\frac{7}{7}=5$ which is exactly what you need.

Comment: Can you show how $a_{n+1} = 6 - \frac 7{a_n+2}$? I didn't follow that.

Comment: $ \frac{6a_n + 5}{a_n + 2}=\frac{6a_n +12-7}{a_n + 2}$

Comment: but $a_n < 5 $ is what we need to prove, so I can't use that

Comment: The symbol used does not matter but use $a_k$ if you prefer.

Comment: @S.Dolan Neat little trick there, I'll have to remember that one!

Comment: oh yes thank you

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $x>0$ (so $x+2>0$),

$x<5\iff 6x+5<5x+10\iff \dfrac{6x+5}{x+2}<5$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The homographic function $\:f(x)=\dfrac{6x+5}{x+2}$ is continuous, increasing on the interval $(-2+\infty)$, so $$f\bigl([0,5]\bigr)=\bigl[f(0),f(5)\bigr]=[3,5].$$

Comment: I am not familiar with the term "homographic function." I see that it means "the quotient of two first-degree polynomial functions" but it doesn't appear to be common enough to have its own wikipedia page. Where, may I ask, did you learn this term?

Comment: You can look at [Homography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography) on Wikipedia with broader  context (in particular homographies in the comples plane), for a more elementary treatment (high school level), if you read french, at [fonctions homographiques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_homographique).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't read French :(

Comment: Anyway, in my answer, the name of this type of function is unimportant. This being said, homography is a an important notion in projective geometry.